# R GPU computing RPUD installation failed

Tags: r, gpu

I am learning GPU Computing with R (http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing).
I am trying to install packages 'RPUD' or 'gputools' but failed. The RPUD version I found works only for CUDA toolkit 8.0/7.5. But I could only download CUDA 9.1. The 'gputools' could not be installed either.Any ideas/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to download CUDA 8.0 here: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-80-ga2-download-archive

Comment: `gputools` was recently removed from CRAN.  The other general purpose CUDA backend `gmatrix` was also removed.  I am not familiar with `rpud`.  If you are open to using an OpenCL backend you can try `gpuR`.  I am currently working on getting the CUDA backend version of it working.